# Draw circle subscribed to a polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps

We have a polygon with an irregular form (in example, a city boundaries polygon).

We need to draw a "circle" with a defined radius (ie, 4km) bound to this polygon, in other words, if point at 4km fall outside the polygon, we need to keep the polygon point as point.

I've attached a sample image, the red border is our polygon, the blue circle is what we need to get. As you can see, the blu circle doesn't exceed the polygon boundaries.

Any help?

[image: circle inside polygon]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use floodfill algorithm to make a set of points inside the shape, then paint points form the set which are not further form center of circle than its radius.

Comment: Thank for the response. Do you have a simple javascript example ?